# Why clang and gcc output different results under `-std=c89` option?

Tags: c, gcc, clang, c89

I came across this [quiz](https://youtu.be/lLv1s7rKeCM?t=670), so want to verify it myself:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void
print_sum(a, b)
{
    printf("%d\n", a + b);
}

int
main(void)
{
    print_sum(1.5, 8.5);
    return 0;
}
```

I used https://godbolt.org/ to test it:
(1) Use `x86-64 clang (trunk)` with `-std=c89` option, the result is `9`;
(2) But `x86-64 gcc (trunk)` with `-std=c89` option, the result is `158013177`.
From my understanding, the default type of `a` and `b` should be `int`, so the `1.5` should be converted to `1` and `8.5` converted to `8` when passing to `print_sum()`. But obviously `gcc` doesn't follow it.

So I am just wondering under `c89`, is this a `gcc` bug or the above program has "undefined behaviour?

Comment: Hint: both compiler will emit warnings for this program.

Comment: It's rather a language bug. This crap feature of "implicit int" should never have existed in the first place and getting rid of it was one of the major improvements that came with C99.

Answer (score 3):

The program has undefined behavior.

This:

```
void
print_sum(a, b)
```

is an "old-style" declaration. It makes `a` and `b` parameters of type `int`, but it doesn't communicate that information to any callers.

This call:

```
print_sum(1.5, 8.5);
```

since the visible declaration is not a *prototype* for the function, causes the compiler to assume that the called function takes two arguments of type `double`. The arguments are not converted from `double` to `int`. They're simply passed as `double`, and the function assumes that it's been given two `int` arguments. The different behavior might be the result of different calling conventions (unlikely since gcc and clang should be compatible), or different optimizations.

The fix is to change the declaration to a prototype, i.e., a declaration that specifies the types of its arguments. Change this:

```
void
print_sum(a, b)
```

to this:

```
void
print_sum(int a, int b)
```

Comment: If a visible declaration is not a prototype for a function, then why does `void print_sum(int a, int b) {... }` work?

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts That **is** a prototype. I didn't say that a visible declaration is not a prototype, I said that that particular visible declaration (`void print_sum(a, b)`) is not a prototype.

Comment: But still getting a warning with `-Wmissing-prototypes`.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts `gcc -Wmissing-prototypes` is warning about something that's valid code: "Warn if a global function is defined without a previous prototype declaration.".  `void print_sum(int a, int b) { printf("%d\n", a + b); }` provides both a prototype and a definition, which is valid. The warning, while not required, is a reasonable one. Note that it applies only to global functions.

Comment: If `print_sum` is defined as `static` (so its name is visible only within that source file), there's no warning. If it's intended to be global, then it *should* have a declaration in a `.h` file and a separate definition in a corresponding `.c` file. The warning makes less sense in a toy example like the code in the question (though I'd still define functions as `static` unless they actually need to be global).

Comment: @KeithThompson Thanks very much for your analysis!
Regarding your comment: "The different behavior might be the result of different calling conventions (unlikely since gcc and clang should be compatible), or different optimizations."
From the assembly code, I can see clang passes `1` and `8` to the `print_sum`. So it seems clang "correctly" deduces the function prototype is `void print_sum(int a, int b)`.